# how to download all videos in playlist and rename them in an arranged order | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, youtube, youtube-dl

I need some music for a project of mine and downloading all of them one by one from a playlist or download from those annoying full of advertisement websites which don't even convert all the music properly is a huge pain.

I've used the python `youtube_dl` module for downloading one video at a time but I've not used `youtube_dl` for anything more than that. Is there a way I can use `youtube_dl` or any other module which downloads songs in an arranged order one by one and renaming the files to `1.mp3`, `2.mp3`, `3.mp3`, ... etc.?

I need them in an arranged order, so I rename them to `1.mp3`, `2.mp3` and so on but my playlist has over 40 videos added to it.

So let's say I have a playlist and the link to it is `https://youtube.com/playlist/abcdefgh`. The code downloads the songs in an arranged order and renames them at the same time. The first video in the playlist will be saved as `1.mp3`, second one on the playlist will be saved as `2.mp3`, fifth video in the playlist be saved as `5.mp3`, 21st video in the playlist saved as `21.mp3` and you get the point.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving your problem

Comment: take a look at the `for` loop and  `enumerate(playlist)`.

Comment: @S P Sharan but i do not know how to get and download videos one by one using `youtube_dl`..